# Why doesn't ivy resolve my dependencies?

Tags: java, jboss, ivy

I have this dependency declared:

```
<dependency org="org.jboss.jbossas" name="jboss-as-parent" rev="6.0.0.20100216-M2"/>
```

And it just fetches the pom.
Other dependencies are resolved just fine.

I'm using ivy 2.2.0 rc1 and ant 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the pom : http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-parent/6.0.0.20100216-M2/jboss-as-parent-6.0.0.20100216-M2.pom

then you'll see the line

-packaging -pom- -/packaging-

In maven this means it's a pom project (as opposed to jar or war) and so doesn't have any jar to go with it. These are usually used to group dependencies / perform functions other than supplying a resource.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your hint!

What I don't get: If I declare the dependency to this pom: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/javaee/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jboss-javaee-5.0.1.GA.pom (which has the same packaging type), ivy fetches the jars in the same directory in the repository even if the pom does not declare any dependencies.

Seems I have to know a lot more about maven in order to use ivy :(.

Comment: I think that has more to do with how Ivy/Maven resolve dependencies. For example I know if you don't specify that a dependency as <type>pom</type> in Maven, it automatically assumes that there is a jar on the server at the location and named :

http://therepository/<groupId>/<artifactId>-<version>.jar

and because the javaee project has a jar alongside it, it grabs it.
I.e. compare the folder listing of 

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/javaee/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/

to

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-parent/6.0.0.20100216-M2/

Comment: You'll see the former has jars and the latter doesn't. Dependency resolution doesn't seem any more intelligent than that.

Regardless, I think the key answer to your question is in the jboss-as-parent.pom itself. The description mentions it is :

"Parent POM for JBoss projects. Provides default project build configuration."

Which (I'm not sure how much you know about Maven), but is basically the equivalent of an abstract class in java. It provides some common configuration to be extended and reused by other projects to avoid duplication rather than to create a resource in its own right.